# Try to solve "(Python) tkinter figures (with colorbar) overlap when using slider "

Tags: python, matplotlib, if-statement, tkinter

For my old problem  [(Python) tkinter figures (with colorbar) overlap when using slider](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70530615/python-tkinter-figures-with-colorbar-overlap-when-using-slider-update) (I add bounty to this problem):

I tried to solve it by considering the following good suggestion:

[tkinter figure (with colorbar) shrinks every time it's displayed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62290179/tkinter-figure-with-colorbar-shrinks-every-time-its-displayed)

However, the new problem popped out.
I rewrote the `update()` function as the following

```
def update(val):
    num_on_slider.append(slider_de.val)
    for ii in range(0,num):
        if num_on_slider[-1] == ii:
                global cbar    # <-------- new
                if cbar:       # <-------- new
                    cbar.remove()       # <-------- new
                    con = ax.contourf(x,y,dfs[ii], levels = levels, cmap=cm.jet, alpha = 0.5, antialiased = True)
                    cbar = fig.colorbar(con,ax = ax)
                    ax.axis([1, 12, 1, 6])
```

No overlap; however, the graph will not change as I move the slider.
It looks like the condition `if cbar:` block the following part of codes being executed.

But in my original problem, I assign `cbar` outside the function

```
    cbar = fig.colorbar(con,ax = ax)
    ax.axis([1, 12, 1, 6])
    # ================================================Slider==========================================
    global slider_de
    slider_bar = fig.add_axes([0.12, 0.1, 0.78, 0.03])     
    slider_de = Slider(slider_bar, 's_bar', 0, num-1, valinit=1,valfmt='%0.0f',  valstep=1)
    num_on_slider = []

    def update(val):
        num_on_slider.append(slider_de.val)
        for ii in range(0,num):
            if num_on_slider[-1] == ii:
                    global cbar
                    if cbar:
                        cbar.remove()
                        con = ax.contourf(x,y,dfs[ii], levels = levels, cmap=cm.jet, alpha = 0.5, antialiased = True)
                        cbar = fig.colorbar(con,ax = ax)
                        ax.axis([1, 12, 1, 6])
                
    slider_de.on_changed(update)
```

So the value of `cbar` should not be `None`.

How to fix the problem?

Thanks!

Comment: It seems like you created a range for the color bar that covers all possible frequencies from the five worksheets. If that is true, just call the color bar initially, remove the call to cbar from the update entirely.

Comment: @Kat You solve my original problem also. Thanks!